# error deploying with hardhat- config issue

Tags: solidity, contract-development, hardhat, ethereum-classic, configuration

I'm having error in my config file:
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

```
  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid value {} for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkHDAccountsConfig.
  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.ropsten.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid value {} for HardhatConfig.networks.ropsten - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkHDAccountsConfig.
  * Invalid value {} for HardhatConfig.networks.ganache - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkHDAccountsConfig.
  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.mainnet.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid value {} for HardhatConfig.networks.mainnet - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkHDAccountsConfig.
  * Invalid value {} for HardhatConfig.networks.polygon - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkHDAccountsConfig.
  
To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/
```

my config file:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");


require('dotenv').config()

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});
const MAINNET_RPC_URL = process.env.MAINNET_RPC_URL || process.env.ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL
const RINKEBY_RPC_URL = process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL
const ROPSTEN_RPC_URL = process.env.ROPSTEN_RPC_URL
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
const MNEMONIC = process.env.MNEMONIC
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
   

    rinkeby: {
      url: RINKEBY_RPC_URL,
      // accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
      },
      saveDeployments: true,
    },
    ropsten: {
      url: ROPSTEN_RPC_URL,
      // accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
      },
      saveDeployments: true,
    },
    ganache: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8545',
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
      }
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: MAINNET_RPC_URL,
      // accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
      },
      saveDeployments: true,
    },
    polygon: {
      url: "https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com/",
      // accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
      },
      saveDeployments: true,

    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    // Your API key for Etherscan
    // Obtain one at https://etherscan.io/
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 100000
  }
};
```

I actually deployed a couple of times smart contracts to different networks with the config file above. Know I don't know what changed.
Any ideas?

Comment: most likely the variables have value `undefined`. Print out their contents within the script.

Comment: And how do I do that? You meant print the env var to see if they are really defined?

Comment: `console.log('Here is rinkeby:', RINKEBY_RPC_URL);`

Comment: I see... so after doing that s appears that all my urls are undefined for some reason. I'll try and change that.

Comment: I can't get the process.env read from my .env file. What I did is like: RINKEBY_RPC_URL='https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/continue_with_api_key' in the.env file and then reads with process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL I'm on windows if that's matter.

Comment: hey did you solved it??
I am facing the same thing, Everything is written correctly idk why it givs out undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you are using what seems to be an `env` variable, so either you add as a prefix `process.env` (if these variables are defined in your .env) or you hardcode the "HTTP" addresses

an example for Rinkeby:

```
rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL || "http://your-rinkeby-provider",
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
      },
    },
```

Your .env should be looking like this:

```
   ETHERSCAN_API_KEY=ABC123ABC123ABC123ABC123ABC123ABC1
   RINKEBY_RPC_URL=https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/
   PRIVATE_KEY=0xabc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc...
```

to access these variables you need to use `process.env`, `process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL` in your `hardhat-config`

Comment: yes I defined them as env var like: RINKEBY_RPC_URL='https://rinkeby.infura.io/apikeyHere' maybe I should add export at the beginning of each env var?

Comment: no you don't need

Comment: I defined them just like that but as strings. It appears that I can't pull them for some reason with process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL for example. Do you have an idea?

Comment: by default you should have this `import * as dotenv from "dotenv";` on your hardhat config, otherwise add it

Comment: I'm importing it with commonjs like: require('dotenv').config() Is that enough? I understood that required is used by default with node.js, so all the import supposed to be with require.

Comment: try and let us know if there is any error msg

Comment: Yes, there's  an error of "undefined" I think the scripts can't read the .env variables I defined there. I am using windows and I'm defining it in the .env file like I mentioned above: RINKEBY_RPC_URL='https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/countinue_with_api_key'

Comment: ok so make it simple forget about the .env and use the link directly on your hardhat-config: 

`rinkeby: {
      url: "rinkeby.infura.io/v3/countinue_with_api_key",
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
      },
    }`

Comment: I think that's kind of security risk move. People could sea my api somehow and even the mnmonic

Comment: who will see it? the only thing that needs to be public is your smart contract

Answer (score 0):

Found the source of my problem.
I used .gitignore file from pre-build .gitignore files folder on github- the node one (can see it [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore)) probably ignored somthing I needed (don't know what exatcly).